# Why do we need to put N before strings in Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, character-encoding, unicode

I'm learning T-SQL. From the examples I've seen, to insert text in a `varchar()` cell, I can write just the string to insert, but for `nvarchar()` cells, every example prefix the strings with the letter N.

I tried the following query on a table which has `nvarchar()` rows, and it works fine, so the prefix N is not required:

```
insert into [TableName] values ('Hello', 'World')
```

Why the strings are prefixed with N in every example I've seen?

What are the pros or cons of using this prefix?

Comment: Isn't the N only needed for literal strings?

Comment: Polish is a non-Latin based language????

Comment: `N` means National, as in "National Varying Character", see [Equivalent ANSI SQL Data Types](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/equivalent-ansi-sql-data-types-HP001032229.aspx).

Comment: I agree with this question and nobody has answered it so far, AFAICT. Maybe it could be restated as “why is it bad to let SQL implicitly convert my `VARCHAR` to `NVARCHAR` when my string literal is ASCII?”.

Comment: This question was already asked and answered here: [What is the difference between varchar and nvarchar?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/144283/439793)

Answer (score 29):

NVarchar is used for Unicode. If your database is not storing multilingual data you can keep using Varchar. As an example: `N'abc'` simply converts your string to unicode.

Comment: Why don't you have to prefix with U instead of N then?

Comment: U could be confused for unsigned as a guess

Comment: `U&'abc'` is the right way to specify Unicode strings. See the [SQL 2003 BNF](http://savage.net.au/SQL/sql-2003-2.bnf.html#Unicode%20character%20string%20literal)

Comment: The N actually stands for "National Language Character" set.

Answer (score 25):

By default SQL server uses the [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) character codes for [varchar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).  It contains most of characters for latin-based languages (English, German, French, etc.)  But it does not contain characters for non-latin based languages (Polish, Russian, etc.).  As stated by @Pieter B, nvarchar is used to get around that issue because it is for [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) which contains those missing characters.  This comes at a cost, it takes twice as much space to store nvarchar than varchar.

Putting N in front of your string ensures the characters are converted to Unicode before being placed into a nvarchar column.  Most of the time you will be okay leaving the N off, but I wouldn't recommend it.  It is a lot better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: Just a clarification: "By default" SQL server uses the encoding corresponding to the Varchar field's collation, which is overridable at the time of creation of the field, generally based on the default collation for your instance. The default collation for your instance can be set at install time, but generally corresponds to the system default locale's CP_ACP. That will be Windows 1252 on a US-English machine, but 932 on a machine with a Japanese system locale, 1251 on a Russian machine, etc. The moral of the story? Use NVarchar :)

Comment: So far this is the only answer that addresses the question as asked "Why use the N prefix on literal strings since SQL will implicitly transcode?".  The other answers are all for a different question "What's the difference between nvarchar vs. varchar?"

Answer (score 22):

**Edit**: Microsoft finally [introduced UTF-8 support](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server/introducing-utf-8-support-for-sql-server/ba-p/734928) in SQL Server 2019 (15.x).  So this answer, originally posted in 2012, is outdated.

---

Because MS SQL Server has poor support for UTF-8 compared to other RDBMS.

MS SQL Server follows the convention, used within Windows itself, that "narrow" strings (`char` in C++, `CHAR` or `VARCHAR` in SQL) are [encoded](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) in a legacy "code page".  The problem with code pages is that they have a limited number of characters (most are single-byte encodings, which limits the reportoire to 256 characters) and are designed around a single language (or group of languages with similar alphabets).  This makes it hard to store multilingual data.  For example, you can't store both Russian and Hebrew data because Russian uses code page [1251](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251) and Hebrew uses code page [1255](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1255).

[Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) solves this problem by using a single giant coded character set with room for more than a million characters, enough to represent every language in the world.  There are several Unicode encoding schemes; Microsoft prefers to use [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16), for [historical reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292150/whats-the-point-of-utf-16).  Because UTF-16 represents strings as a sequence of 16-bit code units instead of the traditional 8-bit, a separate character type is needed.  In MSVC++, this is `wchar_t`.  And in MS SQL, it's `NCHAR` or `NVARCHAR`.  The [`N` stands for "national"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx), which seems backwards to me because Unicode is about *inter*-nationalization, but that's the ISO terminology.

Other SQL implementations let you store [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) text in a `VARCHAR` column.  UTF-8 is a variable-length (1-4 bytes per character) encoding that's optimized for the case when your data is *mostly* in the Basic Latin range (which are represented as the same 1 byte per character as ASCII), but can represent any Unicode character.  Thus, you'd avoid the "twice as much space" problem mentioned by bwalk2895.

Unfortunately, MS SQL Server [does not support UTF-8 `VARCHAR`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/232580), so instead you have to either use UTF-16 instead (and waste space for ASCII text), use a non-Unicode code page (and lose the ability to represent foreign characters), or store UTF-8 in a `BINARY` column (and deal with inconveniences like SQL [string functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx) not working properly, or having to view the data as a hex dump in your GUI DB manager).

Comment: In versions earlier then SQL Server 2012, they ware using UCS-2 encoding, which is strictly 2byte. In newer versions, they are using UTF-16 which is variable length mapping to 4bytes per character (similar as UTF-8 but starting at 2 bytes).